# How to start automatically rvm when open new terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rvm

When I open a new terminal in ubuntu, I have to type this to start rvm :

```
source /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
```

How can I start this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the rvm path to your path environment variable. If you're using a local terminal of your computer, you can add it to `.bashrc` or if you're logging in via another computer, add it to your `.bash_profile`.

In either case, I believe you can add it like

```
export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/bin:$PATH"
```

Or another workaround hack would be to create an alias to the command you are typing.

```
alias rvm="source /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm"
```